# In practice is Linked List addition O(N) or O(1)?

Tags: linked-list

It is said that addition and deletion in a Linked List happens in constant time ie O(1) but access to elements happen in time proportional to the size of the list ie O(N). My question is how can you remove or add any element without first traversing to it ?In that case isn't addition or deletion  also of the order O(N)?

Taking the example of Java , what happens when we use the api like this :

```
   LinkedList stamps = new LinkedList();

   stamps.add(new Stamp("Brazil"));
   stamps.add(new Stamp("Spain"));
   ---
   ----
   stamps.add(new Stamp("UnitedStates");  //say this is kth element in the list
   ----
   stamps.add(new Stamp("India");
```

Then when some one does stamps.remove(k) , how can this operation happen in constant time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting items from a linked list works in constant time only if you have a pointer to the actual node on the list. If the only thing you have is the information that you want to delete the "n"th node, then there is no way to know which one it is - in which case you are required to traverse the list first, which is of course O(n).

Adding, on the other hand, always works in constant time, since it is in no way connected to the number of elements already contained by the list. In the example provided, every call to add() is O(1), not including the cost of calling the constructor of class Stamp. Adding to a linked list is simply attaching another element to its end. This is, of course, assuming that the implementation of the linked list knows which node is currently at the end of the list. If it doesn't know that, then, of course, traversal of the entire list is needed.

Comment: think of the condition where the client of the LinkedList has a call like stamps.add(k,new Stamp("UK") . In that case the operation will take time with complexity O(n) irrespective of the fact that the implementation of the linked list knows which node is currently at the end of the list. Isn't it ?

Comment: Yes, of course. In order to know which node is the "k"-th one, you ALWAYS need to iterate through the contents of the list.